# Updating Newtonsoft.Json to version 10

Tags: .net, json.net, nuget, docusignapi, nuget-package

Whenver I update [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to version 10, I keep getting the following error when running [DocuSign.eSign.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.4)

> The type initializer for 'DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration' threw an exception. I: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.The type initializer for 'DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration' threw an exception.  I: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is keeping me from updating other Nuget packages that I have.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following to the config file:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/dependentassembly-element

Answer (score 0):

The [DocuSign.eSign.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.4) (v2.1.4) depends on [NewtonSoft.Json.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/8.0.3) (v8.0.3). So upgrading to  version 10 will throw the compilation error.

Consider moving your other dependencies into a different project, that way you can upgrade the NewtonSoft.Json.dll in the specific project that needs the new version.

Comment: DocuSign.eSign.dll (v2.1.4) depends on  NewtonSoft.Json.dll  >= v8.0.3, meaning can be any version higher than 8.0.3 - so should not throw compilation error.